# Which single player in the AFL has played for the most clubs?

Tags: australian-rules-football

Which single player in AFL (Australian Football League) history has played for the most clubs/teams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three players have played for five different clubs in the history of the V/AFL:

**Les Abbott** played for Collingwood, Carlton, Richmond, Melbourne, and Sydney between 1904 and 1912.

**Les Hughson** played for Collingwood, Hawthorn, Carlton, St Kilda, and Fitzroy between 1927 and 1937.

**Dale Kickett** played for Fitzroy, West Coast, St Kilda, Essendon, and Fremantle between 1990 and 2002.

If you consider the Brisbane Bears and Brisbane Lions as distinct entities, then you can add **Adrian Fletcher**, who played for Geelong, St Kilda, Brisbane Bears, Brisbane Lions, and Fremantle.